# Is rsync overwriting my `./` directory?

Tags: centos, rsync

I'm new to rsync, but I've noticed that at the top of the "receiving incremental file list" is `./`

Is rsync overwriting the destination's `./` directory? The timestamp of `./` in destination matches the source, so I assume it is, and I can't seem to prevent this using `--exclude './'` or `--exclude '*/'`

Code:

```
rsync -av user@host:/dir1/dir2/ /dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6
```

In pseudocode, I'm trying to rsync all the files inside `dir2` on `host` into `dir6` on the local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./` and `../` are OS shortcuts, created by default.

`./` is just a shortcut to the current working directory, so it's timestamp will always match the timestamp of the directory you're looking at.

As you're using the archive flag, timestamps will be preserved, and thus match the source.

Answer (score -1):

Can you post the exact command you're running? It would help to know what options you're specifying along with the source and destination directories. Sounds to me like you are confused with the source entry. You need to specify if you would like to sync the contents of the source directory or the entire directory itself. Per the manual documentation:

> A trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid creating
>          an  additional directory level at the destination.  You can think of a
>          trailing / on a source as meaning "copy the contents  of  this  direc‐
>          tory"  as  opposed  to "copy the directory by name", but in both cases
>          the attributes of the containing directory are transferred to the con‐
>          taining  directory  on  the  destination.  In other words, each of the
>          following commands copies the files in the same way,  including  their
>          setting of the attributes of /dest/foo:
>
> ```
>           rsync -av /src/foo /dest
>           rsync -av /src/foo/ /dest/foo
> ```